# Compare the values, if they are compound correctly

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

| Filename (I+II+III) | Number (I) | Revision (II) | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100_00-**0**.par | 100_00 | **04** | FALSE |
| 111_11-1.dft | 111_11 | 01 | TRUE |
| 222_**2**2_2.asm | 222_**4**2 | 02 | FALSE |

I am trying to find a solution for my problem. Is it even possible to create a query in MS Access, which tell me, if my "Number" and "revision" values are compounded (without failure) from the value "filename" ? If yes, then selected in my query only the wrong one (false)  ..

The Number and Revision should be compound from Filename

I. Number
II. Revision
III. Extension (doesnt influence my query)

thank you

Comment: `WHERE status = 'FALSE'` comes to mind.

Comment: The question was rather, how to get the status ...

Comment: . . I think you should clarify the question so it is clear that it is about calculating `status`.

Answer (score 0):

Could be:

```
Status: [Filename] Like [Number] & "-" & CStr(Val([Revision])) & "*"
```